# react testing jest - cannot set properties of null (setting innerhtml)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to unit testing. I keep getting this error shows up and I'm not sure why. The other cases I have seen aren't related to jest. So, what is the solution for me? Is it within the component or have i just written the test wrong?

This is the fetch call in the component

```
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)


const fetchList = async () => {    
  
  const newList  =  await fetch("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=created:%3E2017-01-10&sort=stars&order=desc")
    .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
        setLoading(false)
      })
    }
    fetchList()
  }, [500]);

  if (isLoading) return <p className='text-white text-3xl text-center'>Loading...</p>
  if (!data) return <p className='text-white text-3xl text-center'>No profile data</p>
```

This is the test

```
import RepoList from '../components/RepoList'
import {render, screen, act} from '@testing-library/react'

import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'


global.fetch = jest.fn(()=> 
Promise.resolve({
    json: () => 
    Promise.resolve({
        name : "name" , 
        value: "Repo Name"
    })
})
);

describe("RepoList", ()=> {
    it("loads the data on click", async () => {
      await act( async () => render(<RepoList/>))
        expect(screen.getByText("Repo Name")).toBeInTheDocument()
    })
});
```

Comment: Which line throws this error? Can you provide the error stack?

Comment: the first close bracket and close parenthesis underneath ' }) ' expect(screen.getByText("Repo Name")).toBeInTheDocument()